# 'module' object has no attribute 'main_page'

Tags: python, django, django-models

After running the command `./manage.py runserver` I'm getting the following error. I know it's for sure got something to do with the Urls.py `(r'^$',views.main_page),` but can't seem to figure out what needs changes... Any advice?

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from content import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'crosstalk.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^crosstalk/', include('crosstalk.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
(r'^$',views.main_page),
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^js/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'templates/js'}),
(r"^(\d+)/$", "post"),
)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime   import datetime

class Cover(models.Model):  
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
text = models.TextField()
posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post')
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class Post(models.Model):  
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
text = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `main_page` in `views.py`. Do that, including the appropriate handling, and it should work.

It should look something like this:

```
def main_page(request):
    # view stuff goes here
    return something
```

Comment: yeah after much poking around that's what I also figured out. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check you have `main_page` in your `views.py`. Better way would be to put it in quotes as

```
(r'^$','content.views.main_page')
```

assuming that `content` is your app name.